# Ubuntu font override

Tags: fonts

How and what fonts does the Ubuntu system override?

When browsing many sites I see an alternative font than Verdana, overridden by Ubuntu OS.

I would like to set up the same for my Gentoo.

Answer (score 0):

To use, in a **site**, the Ubuntu Google font just put the follow code (from Ubuntu.com source) in the site root html page, **after the  and before the**

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic|Ubuntu+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

Then you can use Ubuntu fonts by changing in the css files the

font-family: Ubuntu

To download, add and use Ubuntu font to your **system** you can use **TypeCatcher**

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. Which is: what fonts does the system override